# error when trying to config mysql cluster on windown

Tags: mysql

I am following the quick start guide "install mysql cluser on windown"
everything was ok until I type this command:

```
 C:\Users\pc\my_cluster>start /B c:\Users\pc\mysqlc\bin\ndb_mgmd -f conf\config.ini --initial --configdir=c:\Users\pc\my_cluster\conf
```

and I got this error : Could neither create or open key

> 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\App lication\MySQL Cluster
>
> Management Server', error: 5 Failed to setup event logging
>
> *Could neither create or open key 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\App*
>
> *lication\MySQL Cluster Management Server', error: 5*
>
> *Failed to setup event loggin

please tell me what's wrong.tks so much

Comment: Can you link the quick start guide you're using? Also, try to check your questions for typos before posting them.

Comment: thank you! this is my guide file http://downloads.mysql.com/tutorials/cluster/mysql_wp_cluster_quickstart_windows.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You should use an administration privilege command prompt.
Right click on "Command prompt" then "Run as administrator".